# Can I install the native Android OS on a non-Google phone?

Tags: rooting, operating-system

Samsung makes up 90% of the Android market where I live, and getting a Nexus/Pixel is difficult and ridiculously expensive, but I really want the raw, native Android OS without any of the vendor's modifications, and able to update to the latest OS whenever it comes out.

If I were to buy an older, second-hand Samsung, would it be possible to root and replace the entire OS with native Android (that which you'd find on Nexus/Pixel)?  Or only some phones (if so, which)?  Or is that not possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to run AOSP like ROM on your device instead of OEM's bloated version. The answer to your question depends on the device you are using. There are a lot of custom ROMs available for devices.

For finding these go to [XDA](http://xda-developers.com) and search for your device.
There you can find all the ROMs available. LineageOS (formerly known as CynogenMod) is the most popular one.

Comment: Is AOSP any different than the OS that comes on a Google phone?  I would think not, but I'd like to check.  I've used Nexus phones for years, and I just want to keep that same experience even though I'm limited to a Samsung phone now.

Comment: AOSP with google apps has the same experience as Nexus or Pixel. Obviously, some things like camera performance will depend on hardware.

Comment: Alright, great.  I guess I'll go to the XDA forums and see if I can't find more information there.  Thanks!